# Formatted Strings while use Ask and AskConfirm

Tags: formatting, wolfram-cloud

What I am trying to do is use AskFunction and CloudDeply to prepare an on-line quiz for students. However, I have found using Ask does not obey formatting for strings in web-form output.  For example, the command

```
Ask[{"ans2", "Problem 2:\n\nWhat is the mass in lbm of an object that weighs 25 lbf?" ->
    "Real"];
```

does not result in multiple lines when the CloudObject is accessed and run on Wolfram Cloud.  Likewise, subscript and superscript formatting does not work.

While using Ask, I can get around the problem using `Column'.  For example,

```
Ask[{"ans2", 
    Column[{"Problem 2:", "--------------------", 
      "What is the mass in lbm of an object that weighs 25 lbf?"}]} ->
    "Real"];
```

works fine for multiple line output (sub- and super-scripts still do not work).  However, if I try

```
AskConfirm["ans2", 
    Column[{"Problem 2:", "--------------------", 
      "What is the mass in lbm of an object that weighs 25 lbf?", "--------------------","You answered `Value`.  Do you want to change your answer?"}]
];
```

I do not get multiple line output.

Is there a work around for this?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might find useful this other post about doing a quiz using FormPage instead of Ask: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/149725/cloud-based-random-question-generator/175865#175865